# How to update custom field in marketo

Tags: marketo

I created a custom field in marketo of type string. I created a custom field with name `RF_techLoadBalancers` and API name `rFtechLoadBalancers`, but now I need to update the API name for this field to `RF_techLoadBalancers` (same as name). From admin in field management I can only change the custom field name but I am not able to change API name.

Answer (score 0):

API names cannot be changed for fields.  You would need to file a support tket for the field to be removed so that you can recreate it with the desired API name.